# Find Project for Replica Island

Tags: android

I have looked around  the net and cannot find a project for this game. Is there a zip file which anyone knows of that I can download. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/source/checkout

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to be a member of something to get the code from here: http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ Also where do I put this: http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/. Thanks

Comment: You need to check out the project using subversion to your local hard drive.

Comment: Raj: Use [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) to checkout the sources, as DKIT's link indicates.  If you need a Subversion client, see here: [http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)  If you are unfamiliar with Subversion, see here: [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have installed it, just need to work out how to import the files now looks a little complicated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry one more thing I put: svn checkout file:///c:/svn-repo/ http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/    it shows as Checked out revision 0 and then Checked out revision 7. But I cannot find the files anywhere. Appreciate any advice on this thanks.

Comment: The command for getting a read-only copy of the project, as of today at least, is:  `svn checkout http://replicaisland.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ replicaisland-read-only`